# Using an answer/response re: boredom

Tags: discussion

I am writing a book, a memoir and a manual.

In it a plan to discuss the self-sabatoging strategy/experience of boredom as it pertains to exercise adherence.  The first reply here is awesome, was wondering if I can use it, in whole or in part, if so what might it require to do so 'skillfully.'  Thanks so much.

Namaste,
Steven Head

Answer (score 0):

If you want to quote something you find on this site, the license terms are identified here -- [Public Network Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing) -- see what that says about "Subscriber Content".

I guess you might also perhaps make another/private agreement with the author of the content that you're intersted in, but I don't know what/which answer you were referring to.